# Using Azure DevOps pipeline variable in Python script using YAML configuration

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am trying to understand why my configuration does not work.

1. I have added the secret value under Variables un Azure Pipeline.
2. I have added the following code in YAML file

   ```
   variables:
     SONAR_API_KEY: $SONAR_AUTH
   ```
3. I have added the secret variable to the Python script like this

   ```
   import requests
   import json
   import os
   import sys

   SONAR_API_KEY = os.environ.get("SONAR_API_KEY")
   ```

   And I call it like this:

   ```
   payload = {}
   headers = {
     'Authorization': f'Basic {SONAR_API_KEY}',
   }
   ```
4. And this is the task for the YAML file that runs the file. File is running well, but I get 401 when calling the API inside the script, yet I do not have any issues testing this locally on my machine.

   ```
     - task: CmdLine@2
       displayName: Retrieve SonarQube
       inputs:
         script: |
           echo -e "Starting the Python script for SonarQube"
           python3.8 $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SonarQube.py
   ```

I tried to add text in variable, just to see if that gets printed when the script is run, it works, but not the secret value.

```
Starting the Python script for SonarQube
$KRISTAPS_TEST
```

As you see it calls "$KRISTAPS_TEST", but not the actual value.

I have added a text value in Pipeline variables, but when I call it from the script it just prints out me this

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import sys

SONAR_SECRET = os.environ.get("SONAR_AUTH")
KRISTAPS_TEST = os.environ.get("KRISTAPS_VARIABLE")

print(KRISTAPS_TEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, will answer my own question guys as this will be useful for others too.

So, what I did instead. I did add the "export" commands in the script part in the YAML configuration file. And that did solve my problem.

```yaml
- task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Retrieve SonarQube
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo -e "Starting the Python script for SonarQube"
        export SONAR_AUTH=$(SONAR_AUTH)
        python3.8 $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SonarQube.py
```

So, you call these variables in the script as follows. We are setting the "os.environ.get("SONAR_AUTH")" to the variable "SONAR_SECRET".

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import sys

SONAR_SECRET = os.environ.get("SONAR_AUTH")

url = "https://***.azurewebsites.net/api/editions/show_license"

# add the user token after "Basic "
payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': f'Basic {SONAR_SECRET}',
}
```